# Angular NG8001: 'app-navbar' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add the navbar to my login page, but for some reason it's throwing the error: "NG8001: 'app-navbar' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1

src/app/login/login.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent."
I'm calling the navbar by using:

`<app-navbar></app-navbar>`

App module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'navbar', component: NavbarComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Login components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

navbar components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Your login component is not in `declarations`.. is it in another module?

Comment: @Jeppe you are right, I didn't notice it. Thanks for opening my eyes :D

Answer (score 4):

Login component was not in declarations